# How to make regex . eat everything?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Im using C++11 regex header and I have a problem:
I want to have regex something like

> "(\d{1,10})\s(.*)"

My problem is that string contains chars that . doesnt match.
Any way to make . match everything. 
If you wonder what it doesnt match:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/

> any character except line terminators (LF, CR, LS, PS).

Worst part is that I guess I could live with alternation(though it is ugly) but IDK how to specify LS and PS in the regex.

Comment: Instead of using `.` does using `[\s\S]` work?

Comment: making ending of regex like this: )\\s([\\s\\S]*) does not work

Comment: Why are you interested in matching the line terminators? Wouldn't it be easier to strip those off the string before matching?

Comment: it is mostly for future, I encountered this problem because I did not properly terminate the string that was bein encrypted so decrypted string also contained padding bytes... but that being said I would like to be able to process a msg that is multiline

Comment: If your input is ASCII encoded, you might be able to use [\x##] where ## is the hex code for the character in ASCII. For LF it's 0x0A, CR it's 0x0D. Alternatively, you can use \u#### for the unicode representation, where #### is the hex value for the unicode character

Comment: `[\s\S]` or `[\d\D]` should work, or it means the library violates the standard. And `.`'s list of does-not-match varies between implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your string does not include NUL characters:

```
[^\0]*
```

Don't forget that \ has to be doubled in strings.

```
"...[^\\0]*..."
```

Comment: raw strings are a nice addition for regex R"([^\0]*)"